# multiprocessing - start new process in a new cmd window - communicate back and forth

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Essentially, I would like to create a new Process that is run in a brand new CMD window (for display output purposes), and allow the original process to communicate back and forth with the new process.

I understand you can open a new cmd window with the subprocess open call, but this does not allow me to run a function that exists within the same script, and communication back and forth seems more difficult to achieve what I'd like.  Likewise, I can start a new Process and communicate with it back and forth easily enough, but can't seem to do so by having it run in a new cmd window.

I feel like this may not be doable, but thought I'd put out the question anyways.

Comment: As an aside - I'll quickly explain what my program is trying to do - in case there are other options.  The main script has to iterate through a list of other scripts, and run them one at a time (currently using subprocess).  I would like to essentially display logging type output on the main console window, and I would like to run the other scripts in a new cmd window and be able to see their output shown there.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416529/355230) and example of one cmd window echoing the output of other programs (which _could_ be other cmd sessions).

Comment: You could also play around with executing `cmd /C yoursubprogram` to see if you could get it to work the way you want. You'll probably need to use something more complex than the usual IPC methods though, since I don't think `cmd` play nice with pipes for standard input and output (but I've not tried it so who knows).

Comment: That's part of the equation - and I actually have something similar already in place - that is, displaying the output of each of the other apps in the current command window.  I forgot to mention - but I also am capturing the output of each of the other scripts for logging purposes.  The difficulty I'm finding currently is being able to run those other scripts via a separate process.

Comment: cmd /c just appears to be another way to run my other scripts, but it would open each of those scripts up in own cmd window, whereas I'd like them to all be run through the one new cmd window.