# Get realtime output from python subprocess

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I'm trying to invoke a command line utility from Python. The code is as follows

```
import subprocess
import sys

class Executor :

    def executeEXE(self,executable ) :

        CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
        process = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW )
        while True:
            line = process.stdout.readline()
            if line == '' and process.poll() != None:
                break
            print line
```

The problem with above code is I want the real-time output of above process which I'm not getting. What I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The way `subprocess.popen()` output is echoed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416529/355230) might be helpful.

Comment: Here's [another couple of articles that won't help you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279) (it seems you are on Windows). At the very least use `iter()`-based loop instead of the `while`-loop.

Comment: @Sebastian I think the `readline()` statement is somehow not returning the output. I'm not sure how `iter()` will help. And yes I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 problems in your code:

1. first of all, readline() will block untill when a new line is printed out and flushed.
   That means you should execute the code

   while True:
       ...

in a new Thread and call a callback function when the output is ready.

2. Since the readline is waiting for a new line, you must use

   print 'Hello World'
    sys.stdout.flush()

everytime in your executable.

You can see some code and example on my git:
[pyCommunicator](https://github.com/jstar88/pyCommunicator)

Instead, if your external tool is buffered, the only thing you can try is to use stderr as PIPE:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902799/2054758

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I understand this problem but I can't find my way out of it. 

When I run the same executable on command line I can see real time output. And I know it enters newlines. 

And about second part I've tried that still that doesn't work out. That should mean process is buffering the output.

Also if possible can I input commands on stdin of the new process and use it like shell?

Comment: yes, just put in your 'executable' variable an array of string command and args

Comment: No. I mean literally like shell.. 

To execute commands on shell, read output and do the same again..