# Send commands to CMD window?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pyinstaller

I'm looking to be able to send commands to the CMD (windows). I need to be able to send multiple commands and have them run on the CMD.

The specific commands I need to send are:

1. `cd "C:\Python27\Scripts"`
2. `pyinstaller.exe --clean --win-private-assemblies -F --onefile –windowed --icon=app.ico app.py`

Is this easily possible?

Comment: yes. use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: you can use a library that makes you able to send key to cmd or other

Comment: If you know the commands in advance, you can create a batch file and execute it as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416529/355230) to a related question.

Comment: You don't need cmd.exe. Just use subprocess for this, e.g. `subprocess.check_call([r'C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe', '--clean', '--win-private-assemblies', '-F', '--onefile', '--windowed', '--icon=app.ico', 'app.py'], cwd=r'C:\Python27\Scripts')`. Passing the `cwd` option is necessary if that's where "app.ico" and "app.py" are located.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you can either user the subprocess module for each command, or you can write all the commands to a bat file and execute that.

```
import os
script = '''
cd "C:\Python27\Scripts" 
pyinstaller.exe --clean --win-private-assemblies -F --onefile –windowed --icon=app.ico app.py
'''

with open('tmpscript.bat') as file_: 
    file_.write(script)
# either system or subprocess will work here
os.system('tmpscript.bat')
```