# file line writing closes off script

Tags: python

I'm looking to make a file that when you enter a directory, it creates a folder inside that directory. I'm using a batch file to create the folder, so I'm making it when you enter the directory, it will write that directory to the batch file, then run it. However I'm having some errors. Here's my code

```
directory = str(input())
text = 'cd ' + directory
lines = open('new.bat', 'r').readlines()
lines[2] = text
out = open('new.bat', 'w')
out.writelines(lines)
out.close()
call('new.bat')
```

`out.close()` exits my python script before it can have a chance to call 'new.bat', however if I move the `out.close()` to after it calls new.bat, it gives me an error that the file is currently being used. How do I fix this?

Comment: Exits? Are you getting an actual exception? Closing `out` should not just silently end the script.

Comment: I enter the directory and it just ends the script with a blank line

Comment: Okay, are you aware that you can't change the directory of the current process via a subprocess? That's what `os.chdir` is for. Sounds like it's working, it's just that a "script" that does nothing but change the directory is going to change the directory in a subprocess, finish almost immediately, and nothing will have changed for the parent.

Comment: Why are you writing a `.bat` file to do these things?

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416529/355230) to another question shows how to create and execute a batch file from Python. I'm fiarly sure it could be adapted to handle what you want to do.