# Invoke & print output of Java using python

Tags: java, python

I have written python code to invoke .java file, compile it & execute it using python. I'm using following python code

```
import os
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE
path='Location where my .java file is'
os.chdir(path)
def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])


def execute_java(java_file):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class]

compile_java('Hello.java')      
execute_java("Hello")
```

My .java file contains simple hello world code. The code is given below

```
public class Hello {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }

}
```

My python code is running successfully but I'm not getting "Hello World" message in my python console. Can you please help me to print java output(Hello World) in my python console? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You never actually run `cmd` using subprocess.

Comment: Something like what is being done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416529/355230) mine would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the command using [popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
def execute_java(java_file):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = 'java '+ java_class
    f = os.popen(cmd)
    print f.read()
```

Comment: Thank you @Bajal.It's working now for single println. But if I want to retrieve if I want to retrieve multiple output using while loop then it is not working. For example it is not working for while (result.next()) {
      //Retrieve by name
      String name = result.getString(1);
      //Retrieve by address
      String address = result.getString(2); 
      //Retrieve by company
      String company = result.getString(3);
      
     System.out.println(name+":"+family+":"+company);
    }  Can you please suggest

Comment: Actually the same code should work for multiple lines output because it just prints out the entire STDOUT.
Is it possible that your resultSet only has one row, by any chance?